# Reference a running thread into a new thread class in python

Tags: python, multithreading

It seems that this is working fine but I cannot stop thinking about whether it is correct or considered best practices for working with multiple threads in Python since it seems quite simple (I don't have experience doing parallel programming in Python) and it might be missing something or having potential issues when the two classes become more complex. I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

```
class Runner1(threading.thread):
    def __init__(self): 
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.n = 0
    def run(self):
       while self.n < 100:
         time.sleep(10)
         self.n += 1


thread1 = Runner1()
thread1.start()

class Runner2(threading.thread):
    def __init__(self, runner): 
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.runner = runner
    def run(self):
       while True:
          print(self.runner.n)
          time.sleep(10)

thread2 = Runner2(thread1)
thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `Thread` object from one thread to another is fine. However, the increment of `n` in `Runner1`'s `run()` method is not atomic, so I would recommend putting a lock around any access to `n`. (Although currently only one thread is modifying it, the moment things get a little more complicated it will become a problem unless the variable is protected.)